# Append on current focused input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a bookmarklet,

[image]

What I am trying to do is, appending an element to current focused input.For example, if user focused (clicked) on textarea, and click my bookmarklet, I want to add "Hello" into that textarea. I have tried this;

```
<a href=" javascript:(function(){
var theDiv = document.getElementById("contentarea");
var content = document.createTextNode("Hello");
theDiv.appendChild(content);
})();
">this</a>
```

But it only works for the div id (contentarea) that I have included. How to append on current focused input ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `document.activeElement`, like:

```
<a href='javascript:(function(){
var theDiv = document.activeElement;
var content = document.createTextNode("Hello");
theDiv.appendChild(content);
})();
'>this</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape the quotes and use `document.activeElement`

```
<a href='javascript:(function(){
var theDiv = document.activeElement;
var content = document.createTextNode("Hello");
theDiv.appendChild(content);
})();
'>this</a>
```

Comment: Although the OP needs to do this, this is not an answer to the question at hand.